# How to fix: "Cannot assign value of type 'SelfieListViewController' to type '(UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate)?'"

Tags: swift

I am getting this error:
Cannot assign value of type 'SelfieListViewController' to type '(UIImagePickerControllerDelegate & UINavigationControllerDelegate)?'

For this function:

```
@objc func createNewSelfie()
    {
        //Create a new image picker
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

        //If a camera is a available, use it; otherwise, use the photo library
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera)
        {
            imagePicker.sourceType = .camera

            //If the front-facing camera is available, use that
            if UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(.front)
            {
                imagePicker.cameraDevice = .front
            }
        }
        else
        {
            imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        }

        //We want this object to be notified when the user takes a photo
        imagePicker.delegate = self

        //Present the image picker
        self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: just add `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate` and `UINavigationControllerDelegate` after your `UIViewController` (SelfieListViewController) declaration `class SelfieListViewController: UIViewController,  UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,  UINavigationControllerDelegate {`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thank you. It solved now! I am new to swift, so I totally missed this point..